# Wildcard not working in cp command when using exec

Tags: command-line, unix, find, cp

I want to copy all the files in all the directories to the parent directory, but I get the error

```
./img/* is not a directory
```

For example. Here is the command that I used. Is there a better way to do this?

```
find . -type d -regex './[a-z]*' -exec cp -v {}/* .. \;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -type d -regex './[a-z]*' -exec bash -c 'cp -v "$1"/* ..' Cp {} \;
```

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
find . -type d -regex './[a-z]*' -exec cp -v {}/* .. \;
```

When bash sees this line, it performs pathname expansion on `{}/*`.  Since there (typically) is no directory named `{}`, the `*` is left as a literal `*`.  This is not what you want.  You need pathname expansion to occur *after* `find` has substituted in for `{}`.  By putting the `cp` command in quotes and passing it as an argument to `bash -c`, we achieve that goal.

A sample form for `bash -c` looks like:

```
bash -c 'code...' a b c
```

This tells bash to assign `a` to `$0`, `b` to `$1`, `c` to `$2` and then execute `code...`.  If an error occurs, the shell uses `$0` as the name of the program being executed (in the error message).  Above, we chose `Cp` as a descriptive name.  Also, as above, `{}` is substituted for `$1` and we use use `$1` in the `code...`.  When used this way, `{}` doesn't need to be quoted (but it doesn't hurt if you do); `find` handles any escaping that is needed.  Inside `code...`, however, `$1` should be in double-quotes to protect against word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain why it works now?

Comment: @AR7 I just updated the answer.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It helps very much. You've made my day.

Answer (score 1):

This might also work

```
cd your_directory
cp -rp * /absolut_path_to_parent_directory
```